# Source not Found Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, buildpath

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eh63.png*

I get this error message every time I enter any of the classes in my project, before it worked really well, but now it seems that there is some problem with my built path, and i don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: You are in the `bin` directory - look in the `src` directory for the .java files. Or use the Package Explorer rather than Navigator.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191998/attach-source-issue-in-eclipse?rq=1 ?

Comment: greg-449, I know that I can access the .java file from Package Explorer, but why Navigator doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

your res (resource) directory is in your classpath, but not your src dir. You must right click on it, click on "build path" and then in "use as source folder" (you can have several different directories as source folder)